# How to generate random number and use it for action?

Tags: javascript, random, splash-screen

My main idea is generating some kind of "random greetings" and the idea is to generate a random number, and depends on the number to display "random greeting".
Here is my non working code:

```
<p class="status">Your random splash screen: <span id="greeting">You don't have one</span></p>
<script>
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
if (x == 1) {
  document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Greeting 1";
} else if (x == 2) {
  document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Greeting 2";
} else if (x == 3) {
  document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Greeting 3";
} else if (x == 4) {
  document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Greeting 4";
}
</script>
```

I have no idea what's wrong in it, please help!

Comment: the code could be less repetitive but it should work

Comment: [Your code works fine.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZywxa)

Comment: See [Getting random value from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-random-value-from-an-array)

Comment: Maybe some kind of race condition is happening? Try putting the script inside the <head>

Comment: checked, it works bro!

Comment: @EmanuelLandeholm There is no race condition happening. Putting the script in the <head> would fail as the #greeting element wouldn't be loaded yet.

Comment: nothing wrong with if else ladder but efficient way would be mapping numbers to greetings like in an array

Comment: There's also no element with the id "greeting". There's a span with the id "greting", which you probably meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see here the code works fine:

```js
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
var greetings = ['Greeting 1', 'Greeting 2', 'Greeting 3', 'Greeting 4'];

document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = greetings[x];
```

```html
<p id="greeting">Nice to meet you!</p>
```

Comment: Did you run the snippet? All we can do is help using the info provided, you'll have to be more detailed with where/how you're trying to use this! Log out `document.getElementById("greeting")` and what do you see?

Comment: I am going to use this @ www.beon.ga while it is loading the website ;)

Comment: Just making some fixes